# Esperanto evolution from "unua libro" to "fundamento"

Tags: history, language-evolution, fundamento

What changes did Zamenhof made to Esperanto from the publication of the *Unua libro* to *La Fundamento de Esperanto*.

I only found the evolution of (correlatives) *-an* to *-am*. I wondered if there were any other changes.

Answer (score 2):

The change of the endings of temporal correlatives from *-an* to *-am* was the only change of something presented in the Unua Libro. Apart from that, there were only additions to the language and more explicit clarification of already existing features.

Comment: [Jes jen Jens](https://www.liberafolio.org/2018/12/04/kien-malaperis-la-unua-libro/#comment-2509) opinias, ke Zamenhof konscie metis al la Unua Libro tian eraron pri la tabelvortoj kun fina _-am_ (nedistingebla de akuzativa _-an_) por distingi inter kritikontoj seriozaj kaj malseriozaj. La seriozaj atentigos pri la eraro kaj la aliaj ne rimarkos ĝin kaj estos nur kverelemaj. Kurioza teorio.

Answer (score 0):

You can find *la unua libro* [here](http://www.genekeyes.com/Dr_Esperanto.html) and *la fundamento* [here](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html) to compare them.